# How to check if sendBroadcast has finished his job

Tags: android

I got little problem. I'm refreshing my sdcard using:

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

and I have created `ProgressDialog` with a spinner which pops out at the start ("at the start" - I mean after sendBroadcast method), and after successful refresh I would like to dismiss it, but I got no idea how to check that `MediaScanner` finished his job. I tried using `BroadcastReciver` and `sendStickyOrderedBroadcast(...)`, but its seems it was wrong idea...

I can't use `MediaScannerConnection` and `OnScanCompletedListener()` because I don't have direct paths to the files (in some situations, it doesn't exist).
Does anyone have any idea how to solve my problem? I have run out of ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you send a broadcast you can't expect a result. 
The only way you will ever get one is if the receiver (in this case the MediaScannerService which catches the ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED broadcast) sends its own broadcast with an update on the "job".

You should be able to catch [ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED) for your current circumstance, however if you want more control (i.e. to scan specific files or a scan progress) you could implement [MediaScannerConnectionClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.MediaScannerConnectionClient.html).